# MathJax not rendering in angular

Tags: angularjs, mathjax

I have used MathJax for a while and have used it in previous angular implementations with the standard directive as shown here.

```
(function ()
{
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.core')
        .directive('mathjaxBind', mathjaxBindDirective);

     /** @ngInject **/
    function mathjaxBindDirective()
    {   return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$watch(attrs.mathjaxBind, function(texExpression) {
                    var texScript = angular.element("<script type='math/tex'>").html(texExpression ? texExpression :  "");
                    element.html("");
                    element.append(texScript);
                    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Reprocess", MathJax.Hub, element[0]]);
                });
            }
        }
    };   
})();
```

And obviously it is called as

```
<span mathjax-bind="obj.data.text"></span>
```

The main difference between the current implementation and previous ones is that the controllers are being called using the "controller as" syntax.

MathJax loads properly and seems to be called properly. The directive is indeed called and the code is placed in the element properly. However, it is not formatted and not shown. It seems like the formatting simply never takes place.

Maybe there is a problem with the scope?

Comment: Joshua, Did you find any solution to this problem?